# カンマで区切られた「2桁の数字」にマッチする正規表現について

Tags: javascript, 正規表現

たとえば、
`123, 45, 67, 890, 10,`
といった数列が用意されていたとして、このときの
,45　と　,67　と　,10
の"カンマだけ"にマッチするような正規表現を考えています。

二桁の要素は、
カンマ→数字→数字→カンマ
であると考えて
`new RegExp(/,[0-9][0-9],/ ,'g')`
としました。

このときカンマだけにマッチさせたいので、最初の文字だけマッチさせるように^をつけました
`new RegExp(/^,[0-9][0-9],/ ,'g')`

ここで、確認用のプログラム

```
var str = "123,45,67,890,10,";
console.log("------------\n");
var matching = str.match(new RegExp(/^,[0-9][0-9],/ ,'g'));
console.log(matching);
```

を走らせたのですが、結果は何もマッチしませんでした。
そこで、「カンマだけをマッチ」を抜きして

```
var str = "123,45,67,890,10,";
console.log("------------\n");
var matching = str.match(new RegExp(/,[0-9][0-9],/ ,'g'));
console.log(matching);
```

を走らせた結果、　,45, と　,10,　が結果として帰ってきましましたが、 ,67　はマッチしませんでした。これは　123/,45,/67,　と文字列が区切られてしまい、67　がマッチングしなかったためであることは理解しています。

私はこの67をマッチングさせる方法と、カンマだけをマッチさせる方法が知りたいです。

Comment: 「"カンマだけにマッチ"」=「2桁の数字の両端のカンマのうち１番目のみにマッチ」で、最終的に取り出したいのは2桁の数字からなる文字列ですよね？

Comment: 「"カンマだけにマッチ"」=「2桁の数字の両端のカンマのうち１番目のみにマッチ」の理解どおりです。わかりにくい説明で恐縮です。
最終的にはカンマだけにマッチさせたいと考えています

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2つ目のカンマを「消費」してしまっていることが問題ですので、[先読み](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead)を使って

```
,[0-9][0-9](?=,)
```

のように書くことができます。

ちなみに`^`は文字列の先頭にマッチするので`^,[0-9][0-9],`という正規表現は、文字列の先頭のカンマ→数字→数字→カンマという部分文字列にマッチします。

Comment: 回答していただいてありがとうございます。なるほど、先読みというテクニックが存在するんですね。
^の理解があまかったみたいです。提示していただいた、正規表現で,45　と　,67　と　,10のマッチを確認しました。もうちょっと考えてみます。

Answer (score 1):

先読みする必要があると思います。
`,(?=\d{2},)`
→後ろに「数字2桁とカンマ」がくる場合のカンマ

,67をマッチさせたい場合は
`,\d{2}(?=,)`

Comment: 回答していただいてありがとうございます。提示していただいた正規表現でのマッチを確認しました。私は先読みという書き方の知識がなかったようです。(?=,)ついてもうすこし勉強しようと思います。